# Me salta error en función de filtrado JAVASCRIPT , NODE , POSTMAN Y MONGODB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, postman, docker-compose

primero de todo gracias por vuestro tiempo.

He creado una funcion en Javascript que filtra los datos de MongoDB por la ultima hora para verlo en Postman.
La funcion va bien porque segun veo en el terminal con los logs consigo los datos, pero a continuacion se crashea la app y no saca los datos por Postman.

Postman me funciona perfecto ya que tengo otra funcion que saca todos los datos de mongoDB,tambien tengo un .post en routes ,etc.. **no pegare todo el codigo por ahorrar espacio y dejarlo mas claro.**

Mi app esta dividida en 3 partes = weather.controller.js , weather.model.js y weather.js en routes.

**Primero el schema de los datos guardados.**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const WeatherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  
    id: {
      type: String
      },
       
    temperatura: {
      type: Number
    },

    humedad: {
      type: Number
    },

    presion_atmosferica: {
      type: Number
    },

    velocidad_viento: {
      type: Number
    },

    precipitacion: {
      type: Number
    },

    radiacion_solar: {
      type: Number
    },

    
    fecha: {
      type: Date, 
      default: Date.now
     }
                              
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('weather', WeatherSchema);
```

**weather.controller.js  ->**

```
const Weather = require('../models/weather.model.js');
const Users = require('../models/users.model.js');
const _ = require('lodash');


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  HELPERS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const log = require('../helpers/logs.helper');
const controllerHelper = require('../helpers/controller.helper');
const messageHelper = require('../helpers/message.helper');
const { Console } = require('winston/lib/winston/transports');
const { query } = require('winston');

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  CONSTANTS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Controller Name
const CONTROLER_NAME = 'weather'

//Module Name
const MODULE_NAME = `[${CONTROLER_NAME} Controller]`;

//Error Messages
const GS_CT_ERR = `${CONTROLER_NAME} not Found`;

//Success Messages
const GS_CT_DELETED_SUCCESSFULLY = `${CONTROLER_NAME} deleted successfully`;


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  PUBLIC METHODS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//READ MEASURES

    exports.measures = async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        
        const verb    = "measures";
        var params    = req.params;
        
        var ultimaHora = new Date();
        log.info(ultimaHora);
        log.info(ultimaHora.getTime());
        ultimaHora = ultimaHora.getHours();

        var horacreacion = 0 ;
        ultimaHora--;
        log.info(ultimaHora);
        
        let query = req.query;

        log.info(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb} (IN) --> params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}}`);

        query = {};
        Weather.find(query)
        .then(result => {

          var filtrado = [];

          for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){ 

          horacreacion = result[i].fecha.getHours();
          log.info(horacreacion);
          //var horacreacion = new Date(result[i].fecha);

            if (horacreacion >= ultimaHora) {

            filtrado.push(result[i]);
            log.info("CORRECTO");

            }
        }





        log.info(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb}  (OUT) --> result: ${JSON.stringify(filtrado)}`);
        res.send(filtrado);

        }).catch(err => {
          log.error(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb} (ERROR) --> params: ${JSON.stringify(err)} `)
          res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || `Some error occurred while retrieving ${CONTROLER_NAME}.`
          });
        });

        
        //const resultado = await Weather.find().sort({ fecha: -1 }).limit(120).lean();

        log.info('hola');
        res.send(filtrado);

      } catch (error) {
        controllerHelper.handleErrorResponse(MODULE_NAME, "measure", error, res);
      }
    };
```

**Y weather.js de ROUTER para hacer la llamada por Postman. ->**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const weather = require('../controllers/weather.controller.js');

router

  .get('/measures',    weather.measures)

module.exports = router;
```

**Finalmente al hacer la llamada por Postman de la funcion de controller me devuelve Error. ->**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Finalmente comprobando con log.info en el terminal de visual studio sí que salen bien los datos.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Muchas gracias!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás mezclando `async` con `then`. Tal como tienes tu llamada al método `find` del modelo, haces uso de `then`, por lo cual el resultado de tu llamada sólo estará disponible dentro de la función callback que pasas a ese método.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Si decides apegarte al uso de `then` para recibir el resultado de la llamada a `find` entonces debes enviar la respuesta al cliente desde la función callback que pasas a dicho método `then`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
Weather.find(query)
.then(result => {
  const filtrado = [];
  for(let i = 0; i< result.length; ++i) {
    const horacreacion = result[i].fecha.getHours();
    log.info(horacreacion);
    if (horacreacion >= ultimaHora) {
      filtrado.push(result[i]);
      log.info("CORRECTO");
    }
  }
  log.info(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb}  (OUT) --> result: ${JSON.stringify(filtrado)}`);
  return res.send(filtrado);
});
```

Nota que la llamada a `res` se realiza dentro del callback que pasamos al método `then`.

Otra forma de hacerlo es usar `await` sobre la llamada al método `find`, ya que te encuentras dentro de un método `async`. Por ejemplo:

```js
const result = await Weather.find(query).exec();
const filtrado = [];
for(let i = 0; i< result.length; ++i) {
  const horacreacion = result[i].fecha.getHours();
  log.info(horacreacion);
  if (horacreacion >= ultimaHora) {
    filtrado.push(result[i]);
    log.info("CORRECTO");
  }
}
log.info(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb}  (OUT) --> result: ${JSON.stringify(filtrado)}`);
return res.send(filtrado);
```

Nota que hemos encadenado el método [`exec`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) que efectivamente devuelve una Promesa.

Las llamadas a los métodos de consulta (`find`, `findOne`, etc.) [no devuelven Promesas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises), sino que devuelven un objeto [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Finalmente, el método yo lo escribiría parecido al siguiente:

```js
exports.measures = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const verb = "measures";
    const params = req.params;
    let ultimaHora = new Date();
    log.info(ultimaHora);
    log.info(ultimaHora.getTime());
    ultimaHora = ultimaHora.getHours();
    let horacreacion = 0 ;
    ultimaHora--;
    log.info(ultimaHora);
    const query = req.query;
    log.info(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb} (IN) --> params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}}`);
    const result = Weather.find(query).exec();
    const filtrado = result.filter(r => r.fecha.getHours() >= ultimaHora);
    log.info(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb}  (OUT) --> result: ${JSON.stringify(filtrado)}`);
    return res.send(filtrado);
  } catch (error) {
    log.error(`${MODULE_NAME}:${verb} (ERROR) --> params: ${JSON.stringify(err)} `)
    return controllerHelper.handleErrorResponse(MODULE_NAME, "measure", error, res);
  }
};
```

**Nota**

Una sugerencia personal es que no mezcles el uso de declaraciones usando `var` con `let` y `const`. Actualmente, y supongo que usas una versión de Node actual, el soporte para `let`y `const` está más que garantizado.

Otra sugerencia es que en las funciones *middleware* de Express, utilices siempre el llamado al método `res` anteponiendo un `return`. Esto indica la finalización de la lógica del *middleware* y te evitará errores del tipo:

> Headers already sent

Por último, pero no menos importante, trata de sasnitizar las variables que provienen del lado cliente. Tienes algo como esto:

```js
const query = req.query;
Weather.find(query)...
```

Lo cual no es del todo seguro, te sugiero que leas sobre [Query injection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection-) y los riesgos de no sanitizar las consultas o querys que provienen del cliente.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! me ha servido perfectamente :)